# Knapsack like problem with nonnegative weight constraint

Tags: knapsack-problems

I am dealing with a knapsack-like problem with one difference from the conventional problem: the “weights” can be positive or negative and the constraint is $\sum w_i x_i \ge 0$ instead of $\sum w_i x_i \le W$. The "values" can also be positive or negative.

Can this be transformed to a knapsack problem or is it some other type of combinatorial optimization problem?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/405353/37212, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/144449/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values $v_i$ of the items are non-negative you can simply "buy" all items with positive weights. Let $S = \{i \mid w_i \le 0\}$, $W = \sum_{i \not\in S} w_i$ and $V = \sum_{i \not\in S} v_i$. Your problem then becomes a standard Knapsack problem:

$$
\max \sum_{i \in S} y_i v_i \quad \mbox{s.t.}\\
\sum_{i \in S} -w_i y_i  \le W, \\
y_i \in \{0,1\} \quad \forall i \in S.
$$

Once a solution for the new problem is found, a solution for the original problem can be recovered by setting:
$$
x_i = \begin{cases}
y_i & i \in S \\
1 & i \not\in S
\end{cases}
$$

The value of the new solution will be $\sum_i x_i v_i = V + \sum_{i \in S} y_i v_i$.

Comment: Thanks both, for the nice solution! I guess with the nonnegative constraint you meant the other way around -- buy all items with positive weights and then choose negative-weight items using knapsack solution? Then it will go through.

Sorry I forgot to mention that the values can also be negative, so that potentially positive-weight items with negative value can be used to provide "space" for negative-weight items with (more) positive value?